# Explanation of sinusoidal function: $f(x,y) = A\cos(2\pi(ux + vy) + \phi)$

Tags: signal-processing, image-processing

I never got to take a signals and systems course and this has come up in the math of my image processing review.

Can this be explained?  The equation for a sinusoidal signal is $f(x,y) = A\cos(2\pi(ux + vy) + \phi)$  What do these pieces mean and what is a good way of visualizing it?

Comment: Have you tried plotting it? Would that help?

Comment: A start: The absolute value of $A$ is the *amplitude*.  If $ux+vy\ne 0$, then $1/(|ux+vy|)$ is the *period*.

Comment: More: So if say $u$ and $v$ are constants, the signal has period $1/|k|$ om the line $ux+vy=k$. The constant $\phi$ represents a phase shift from the standard cosine function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think it would be best to see first what happens in one dimension.

I have an example for the  function $y=A\cos(\omega\theta+\phi)$.

- For the  graph of  $$y=A\cos(\omega\theta+\phi)$$

  - $A$ is the  *amplitude*. The crest of the wave has height $ A$.

    $\omega=2\pi f$ where $f$ is the  *frequency*. One complete wave  is generated over an interval of length $T={1/ f}={2\pi\over\omega}$.

    $\phi/\omega$ is the  *phase shift*. The wave  "starts''  at $(-\phi/\omega,0)$.

[image]

---

If you like, you may download an interactive version of the above diagram [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?qmrde8ewe3ay1vi). You may use the sliders on the top, left, and bottom, (by clicking and dragging the "circle") to change the parameters $A$, $\phi$, and $\omega$.